# Converting JS to TS for Angular: error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm migrating my website to Angular and I'm getting this error when trying to compile the js into ts for my navbar. Looked around and found similar issues from other users but they weren't using it in the same context.

Here is the full script and ive commented where the error is:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
      nav = document.getElementById(navId),
      bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
      headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)

    // Validate that all variables exist
    if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // show navbar
        nav.classList.toggle('show')
        // change icon
        toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
        // add padding to body
        bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
        // add padding to header
        headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
      })
    }
  }

  showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header')

  /*===== LINK ACTIVE =====*/
  const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link')

  function colorLink() {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      this.classList.add('active') //error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    }
  }
  linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))

  // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

***EDIT***

Come to find out the whole linkcolor section was controlled via my navbar script using the angular routerLinkActive. I was able to remove the whole link active section of this script and had zero problems. Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: Try to steer clear of using `this` where possible. You could easily use the `event` argument that will be passed to your callback to determine the clicked element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to add the type for this to your click function.

https://www.valentinog.com/blog/this/#typescript-and-this

```
function handleClick(this: HTMLElement) {
console.log("Clicked!");
this.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `event` argument passed to your callback. You can then use `event.currentTarget` to figure out which `link_color` element was actually clicked.

```
  function colorLink(event: Event) {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      event.currentTarget.classList.add('active') //error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    }
  }
```

See [documentation for Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) for more info.

As an added bonus, this will work whether you use arrow functions or not...

```
  const colorLink = (event: Event) => {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      event.currentTarget.classList.add('active') //error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function colorLink() {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      this.classList.add('active') //error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    }
}
```

Write this as an arrow function. `this` keyword is in the function scope, not the event listener scope.

So that part should be:

```js
const colorLink = () => {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      this.classList.add('active') //error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will help, OP _wants_ the `this` that is the scope of the caller to figure out what element was the focus of the click event.

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Cuz this.classList when you use function is actually the object created by the function using new (function constructor)